# How can I place a div at the bottom of another div (so within the bigger div)?

Tags: html

How can I place a div at the bottom of another div (so within the bigger div) ?

[image]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Align Div To Bottom of Parent Div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2306292/align-div-to-bottom-of-parent-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With CSS:

```
Div1 {position:relative;}
Div2 {position:absolute;bottom:0}
```

Comment: I think you mean `absolute` on the 2nd div.

Comment: This didn't quite work. But I changed it into:
Div2 {position: absolute; bottom: 0}
and now it's working. (:

Comment: @EatMyPickle Yeah, that was my mistake in my haste to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/PvSra/

Simply set the outer div to `position:relative` and the inner to `position:absolute` and `bottom:0`.